# Replace array value in multidimensional array - basic Q

Tags: multidimensional-array, replace

my question seems pretty basic, but i can't get around it. I try to replace the second value in a multidimensional array with another array, which happens, but i loose it in my foreach loop. Everything is just an example. So failures like missing quotes happend in here. The original is a function inside a class. Thanks!

This is how the config array looks like:

```
$config_arr = array(  
  'foo_a' => array( 'foo_a_singular', 'foo_a_plural', array('assign_me_aa', 'assign_me_ab') );  
  'foo_b' => array( 'foo_b_singular', 'foo_b_plural', 'assign_me_b')
);
```

This how the processing happens:

```
function process_foo( $config_arr ) {  
  foreach ( $config_arr as $config_data ) { 
  $replacement_data = array( 'bar_me', 'bar_her', 'bar_some' );  
  $config_data[1] = $replacement_data;  
  var_dump($config_data);  
  }
  print_r( $config_arr );  
}
```

The `var_dump` shows me that i replaced/added the data, but the `print_r` tells me that nothing happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point is that I tried to use a numerical index `$config_data[1]` for a associative array: `'foo_b' => array( 'foo_b_singular', 'foo_b_plural', 'assign_me_b')`, which will never work. You have to use stuff like `key()` or `array_keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll brush up on this answer in a minute, but either the scope is local for config_data or you can only read and not write. I've had this problem before. you have to use the actual config_arr in the loop, this can be accomplished with a counter variable. someone else might know a better/different way to do this.

Comment: `private $names; public function __construct( $config_arr) { $this->names = $config_arr; }` is much like the beginning of my class, so it's stored over there. I then rework the $config_arr when it runs through one fn after the other. I also tried `private $counter; (in __construct:) $this->counter = count($config_arr);` and use this to loop through. Fun as it is: no difference...